# run-time error '2467': the expression you entered refers to an object

Tags: ms-access, runtime-error, form-load

I'm NOT an expert, newbie at most but not even there yet . I somehow got stuck with a run-time error '2467': the expression you entered refers to an object that is closed or doesn't exist that i cannot debug.

I have a main form basically containing a box object and some command buttons. On the click event of every button the sourceobject of the box changes to a form and applies a filter to it using the .filter and .filteron=true statements.
I successfully added sourceobject and applied filter to one of the forms, but with the other one, which has almost identical vba code, i couldn't.  When the button click event executes on the main form i get the run-time error 5 invalid procedure call or argument, debug window sending me to the form that i set as recordsource highlighting the if me.filteron=true line. Going deeper and checking the arguments of the procedure i find that all arguments referenced with me.whateverobject generates the run-time error 2467, suggesting that somehow the form isn't loaded into memory, unlike the other form.  I have to mention that otherwise when i open the form directly in form view it works flawlessly.
I tried referencing all my object in the form with form_myformname and it does somehow work  until some point where i get stuck again with the .recordsetclone and .bookmark syntaxes.  But i guess I'm on a goose hunt on this path because as i recall access bookmarks fields of an active form, right?
I'm thinking there has to be a way to force the second form to which i set the box.sourceobject to also load into memory same as the first one, and avoid the above bugs.

Any thoughts on this? Anyone?

I also tried inserting right at the beginning of the sub before setting the sourceobject:
`form_formname.load Me.box.recordsource = "form.formname"`
But failed

Later edit:
I forgot to mention that if i don't set any filter to the form from the mainmenu button click event, the form loads and acts normal as a box.sourceobject

Comment: I have never seen `form_formname.load`. Post the procedure code you are attempting to execute, not scattered lines in your narrative.

Comment: in short we need a minimal reproducible example:
 https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example  Is the box a combobox, listbox, subform, or even a textbox?  At this point my best guess is that recordsource takes a string.  That string corresponds to either a table or a query.  For instance, Me.box.recordSource = "TableA" or Me.box.recordSource = "QueryA"  So, whatever form or control whose recordSource you are trying to access, if it is a query try explicitly saving the query and then referencing it.